# Remove forward slash from URL jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove the first "/" from the following code

```
if ($(this).find('img').length){
   var url = new URL($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
   $("#ajaximageid").val(url.pathname);
}
```

I have tried to use

```
url.replace("/","")  but I get an error.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `new URL()` ?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon a DOM API constructor for creating URLs and processing them to hash/search/pathname etc.

Comment: Why don't you use just var url = $(this).find("img").prop("src") and then $("#ajaximageid").val(url.replace("/", "")); ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank, never heard of it and couldn't find any doc about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've test the url object and find out you can't remove the first `/`.

Event if you do `url.pathname = 'test';`, the pathname is `/test`.

What you can do is, when you use it, you cut the first character :

```
$("#ajaximageid").val(url.pathname.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing it when you're extracting the source of the image

```
var url = new URL($(this).find('img').attr('src').replace("/", ""));
```

When you're calling replace the way you are currently, you're attempting to perform that action on a URL object, not a string. Try what I've recommended so you can do it pre-emptively

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if ($(this).find('img').length){
    var srcImg = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    srcImg = srcImg.substring(0, srcImg.indexOf("/")) + srcImg.substring(srcImg.indexOf("/") + 1, srcImg.length);
    var url = new URL(srcImg);
    $("#ajaximageid").val(url.pathname);
}
```